# Iterating through each line of a file

Tags: c++, loops, file-io, formatting, getline

I am constructing a program that reads a file as input, outputs the file to the console and performs some calculations on some of the input. The input file is a list of substances and their boiling points like this:

```
Acetaldehyde    20.8
Acetone     50.5
Acetylene   -84
Ammonia     -35.5
```

There are about 4x more substances than this in total. My problem is with reading each line of the file. What I have so far will read the first line and then terminate my loop. Whenever I try to use getline I end up with only the temperatures and not the names.

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   ifstream inData;
   inData.open("input.txt");

   string substanceName;
   int boilPoint, min, max;

   cout << "Common Chemicals and Substances: " << endl;
   cout << endl;
   cout << left << setw(20) << "Substance" << right << " " << "Boiling Point" << endl;
   cout << setw(35) << setfill('-') << " " << endl;
   cout << setw(35) << setfill(' ') << " " << endl;

   inData >> substanceName >> boilPoint;
   while (inData)
   {
      cout << left << setw(20) << substanceName
           << right << " " << boilPoint << endl;
      inData >> substanceName >> boilPoint;
   }
   inData.close();
   return 0;
}
```

The output looks correct but is missing all other substances in the file

```
Substance            Boiling Point
---------------------------------- 

Acetaldehyde         20
```

My main goal here is to iterate through each line without getting into more complex code. I think there is just something wrong with my loop but I cannot find out what. Or I am supposed to use getline but I do not understand how to use it and also account for both the string and the int variables coming in from the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to read the boiling point as an integer, but in the file it's floating point. So, it stops reading the first boiling point at the `.` (that's why the boiling point of Acetaldehyde is showing up as 20 instead of the 20.8 that the file contains). That gets things out of sync, so it tries to read the `.8` as the second name (which succeeds, even though it's not what you want), but then tries to read the next name (Acetone) as an `int`, which obviously fails, leaving the stream in a failed state, and breaking out of the loop.

Change `boilPoint` from `int` to `double` and things should work better.

Comment: Yup, this is exactly my problem. I knew it was something simple and I just needed another pair of eyes. Thank you for your comment and for explaining it so well.